# Find the number of cubic roots of unity in $\mathbb{Z}/_{2821}\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let's say I have a number like $2821$, which equals $7$ x $13$ x $31$.

Now let's say I want to determine the number of solutions to the congruence $x^3 ≡ 1$ mod $2821$ (this is the number of cubic roots of unity in $\mathbb{Z}/_{2821}\mathbb{Z}$).

How could I prove that the answer is $27$?

So far I understand that each of the congruence equations $x^3 ≡ 1$ mod $7$, $x^3 ≡ 1$ mod $13$, and $x^3 ≡ 1$ mod $31$ each have 3 solutions and that by the Chinese Remainder Theorem this means that $x^3 ≡ 1$ mod $2821$ must have $3^3$ solutions, but my question is why.

So I am asking:
How can I prove that each of the three equations mod $p$ where $p$ is $7$, $13$, and $31$ above each have $3$ solutions? And how does the Chinese Remainder Theorem imply that this means $x^3 ≡ 1$ mod $2821$ would have 27 solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

$x^3-1=(x-1)\left(x^2+x+1\right)$.

If $31\mid x^3-1$, then by Euclid's lemma either $31\mid x-1$ or $31\mid x^2+x+1$.

$x\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ is a solution. If $x\not\equiv 1\pmod{31}$, then $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod{31}$, i.e. $(2x+1)^2\equiv -3\pmod{31}$. Note $x\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ is not a solution. Since $2^{-1}$ exists mod $31$, this is equivalent to solving $y^2\equiv -3\pmod{31}$. By [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B13) (since $31\equiv 1\pmod{3}$) a solution exists. If $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod{31}$, then $31\mid (x+y)(x-y)$, so there are exactly two solutions.

Use the same method to prove $x^3\equiv 1\pmod{7},\, x^3\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ have exactly three solutions each. Then by CRT there are $3\cdot 3\cdot 3=27$ solutions to $x^3\equiv 1\pmod{7\cdot 13\cdot 31}$.

Comment: Why does CRT allow me to just multiply the number of solutions together though? I know that it does, but wasn't sure if it's a direct implication of the theorem or not.?

Comment: @Jimm Let $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ be the solutions of $x^3\equiv 1\pmod{7}, x^3\equiv 1\pmod{13},x^3\equiv 1\pmod{31}$, respectively. Then $x\equiv a\pmod{7}, x\equiv d\pmod{13},x\equiv g\pmod{31}$ gives one solution, $x\equiv a\pmod{7}, x\equiv d\pmod{13}, x\equiv h\pmod{31}$ gives another, $x\equiv a\pmod{7}, x\equiv d\pmod{13}, x\equiv i\pmod{31}$ gives another, $x\equiv a\pmod{7}, x\equiv e\pmod{13}, x\equiv g\pmod{31}$ gives another, etc. You get $3\cdot 3\cdot 3$ solutions by [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: Ahah. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}$

For your first question, how to exhibit the solutions in $\ZZ/p \ZZ$ of $x^3 -1 = 0$ as an equation in $\ZZ/p\ZZ[x]$: This can in general be done by factoring $x^3 -1$ in the ring $\ZZ/p\ZZ[x]$ with the help of a computer algebra system, e.g. Macaulay 2 can do this, and considering the linear factors. But for $p$ small, as in your example you can, again with the help of a computer program, simply test all numbers from $0$ to $p-1$.

Now your second equation:

The elements of $\ZZ/2821\ZZ$ are in one to one correspondence with the triples

$$\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \mid x_1 \in \ZZ/7 \ZZ, x_2 \in \ZZ/13\ZZ, x_3 \in \ZZ/31\ZZ\}$$

and solutions $w$ of $x^3-1$ in $\ZZ/2821\ZZ$ correspond to triples $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$, where each $w_i$ is a solution to $x^3-1$ in the respective factor ring $\ZZ/7\ZZ, \ZZ/13\ZZ, \ZZ/31\ZZ$.

Now to answer your second question is just to note that the cardinality of a product of finite sets is the product of the cardinalities of the factors.

Comment: You don't need a computer algebra system to prove that $x^3-1$ has three roots in those fields. It has three roots whenever $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Comment: One surely does not need to use a CAS to prove that there are three factors, but it is an easy way to find the solutions explicitly.

Comment: The question was to find the number of solutions, and it is a learning exercise, so if the question was to find the solutions, it would be of no use *as a learning exercise* to use a CAS.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compute $x^3$ for
$$x=\begin{cases}
2,3 & \text{if}\enspace p=7,\\
2,3,4,5,6 & \text{if}\enspace p=13, \\
2,\dots,15 & \text{if}\enspace p=31.
\end{cases}$$
You'll find $3$ solutions in each case:
$$\begin{cases}
\{1,2,-3\} & \text{if}\enspace p=7,\\
\{1,3,-4\} & \text{if}\enspace p=13, \\
\{1,5,-6\} & \text{if}\enspace p=31.
\end{cases}$$
So there are $3^3=27$ solutions in $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/13\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/31\mathbf Z $, hence by the *Chinese Remainder theorem* there are $27$ solutions in $\mathbf Z/2821\mathbf Z$.